# emxFree_real_T Causing Executable to Abort

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

I'm working with Matlab coder, using variable size variables pointed out with `coder.varsize`. This causes some variables to be declared with the type `emxArray_real_T`, be initialized with `emxInit_real_t`, be used with appropriate calls to  `emxEnsureCapacity_real`, and finally be released with usage of `emxFree_real_T`.

I have several functions in which this happens, but sometimes, for reasons I can't isolate well, the `emxFree_real_T` operation causes the compiled executable to abort, showing a backtrace and a Memory Map which don't seem helpful to me. This can be guessed because it happens when a variable size array stops being used (hence can be de-allocated).

By manipulating the C code, I can tell that the errors occur precisely on the calls to `emxFree_real_T` function. Commenting out those lines makes the generated code work fine. But this seems both unsafe and a no-solution for my problem.

Unfortunately, this error is hard to reproduce, so I could not come up with a minimum working example.

Is this a known bug? I'm I missing something regarding the usage of variable size arrays?

Matlab version is R2019a.

Comment: Common for things like this to happen with memory corruption. Have a look at [these debugging steps](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/435205-how-can-i-debug-code-generated-using-matlab-coder-that-crashes-or-gives-incorrect-results) to see if they give you any info, especially checking for runtime errors.

Comment: @RyanLivingston For info, I'm already generating, compiling and running standalone code. The [flowchart in your link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/coder/ug/preparing-matlab-code-for-c-c-code-generation-workflow.html) suggests to create mex-functions as a first step, why is that?

Comment: Also, enabling compiler warnings with `-Wall` and using the check for run-time errors yields only a message "`%lld` expects argument of type `long long int`, but argument 3 has type `long int` [-Wformat]", which happens in the NNN_rtwutil function.

Comment: Runtime error checking. Standalone code doesn't have these checks by default. So if your MATLAB code does something illegal like indexing out of bounds, the generated code will have undefined behavior, corrupt memory, etc. The `cfg.RuntimeChecks` option in the link I sent will enable those checks for standalone code. Try turning that on and running your standalone code to check for errors.

Comment: @RyanLivingston : I've solved the problem for my case, but your hints were on point. Feel free to edit my answer or add one of your own based on what I wrote. If you do, I'll accept yours as the right answer.

Comment: Glad it helped! Let's stick with your answer. I suggest adding the debugging steps link to your answer as we'll keep those up to date over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can have several causes, and the investigation starting point is enabling the option `cfg.RuntimeChecks`, as pointed out by @RyanLivingston. There are other steps [suggested by MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/435205-how-can-i-debug-code-generated-using-matlab-coder-that-crashes-or-gives-incorrect-results) when debugging generated code.

In this case, the `%#codegen` directive already forbids the user from allocating memory dynamically by increasing the size of an array with:

```
myArray(end+1) = rand();
```

However, if the code implements it as:

```
for i:1:a
    myArray(i) = rand();
end
```

Then it may have no means to know that the parameter `a` will surpass the size of `myArray`, and at each step, it will not increase its size with `emxEnsureCapacity`. Adding the `cfg.RuntimeChecks` will create an exception handling case that will pinpoint this occurrence.

A solution for this, would be assigning a larger variable to `myArray`, such as in:

```
myArray = zeros(a,1); 
for i:1:a
    myArray(i) = rand();
end
```

Even if `myArray` had previously been defined with a a smaller size (but set to be variable in size with `coder.varsize`), the increased capacity will be ensured  and the loop can proceed.